# How to toggle Twitter Bootstrap tab panes with <select> <option>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Need to switch tabs with `select`. What's the best practice? My idea is to manipulate class `.active` with `onChange` event. But I believe there must be something better.

Here's some code sample:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="tab1">Tab 1</option>
<option value="tab2">Tab 2</option>
<option value="tab3">Tab 3</option>
</select>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
    <div id="calendari_3">asd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
    <div id="calendari_1">qwe</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
    <div id="calendari_2">asw</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I guess you can call the 'show' method yourself, on any event.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Wv5h/40/ [updated]

JS:

```
// jQuery and Bootstrap loaded, you're here on a $(document).on('ready') scope !
$('#your-select').on('change', function (e) {
    // With $(this).val(), you can **(and have to!)** specify the target in your <option> values.
    $('#the-tab li a').eq($(this).val()).tab('show');
    // If you do not care about the sorting, you can work with $(this).index().
    // $('#the-tab li a').eq($(this).index()).tab('show');
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id='mySelect'>
        <option value='0'>Home</option>
        <option value='1'>Profile</option>
        <option value='2'>Messages</option>
        <option value='3'>Settings</option>
    </select>
</form>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha didn't understand that you did not want the ul anymore, of course you can hide it !

Comment: Forked: replacing `ul` with `select` automatically with jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/Moor/VekSp/1/

Comment: Okay, interesting, but why don't you just replace the DOM structure initially ? I don't think it's required to have this <ul> at the beginning, isn't it ?

Comment: Just for clarity: You need the UL/LI stuff so the bootstrap tabs api works correctly. So include it and add `display:none` to hide it.  I tried doing it with just the `select` and the tab panes don't function correctly.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer will work for a single set of tabs. If you need to trigger multiple sets of tabs with different select boxes, use the following js:

```
$('.select-nav').on('change', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('a[href="' + id + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Thanks for the inspiration for this Flo-Schield-Bobby!

Comment: Your welcome ! However, you need to precise the "id" as value for your different options :)

Updated JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FloSchieldBobby/7Wv5h/210/

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby if you use an id you won't be able to affect multiple select boxes though.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, could you please update the JSFiddle ?

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby I just meant that it isn't as modular, you would need to specify each one if you use an id http://jsfiddle.net/7Wv5h/212/

Comment: I get it, but in your example, which value would contain the "id" var ?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution where you don't need to keep the links. Just the Select.

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function (e) {
  var $optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  $optionSelected.tab('show')
});



<select class="form-control" id="mySelect">
    <option data-target="#home">Home</option>
    <option data-target="#profile">Profile</option>
    <option data-target="#messages">Messages</option>
    <option data-target="#messages">Settings</option>
</select>        


<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    Home
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">.
    Profile
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
    Messages
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
    Settings
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed a solution to handle multiple tabs on the page and no other solution suited me. So I quickly made this: https://gist.github.com/kingsloi/7ab83b6781636df1fbf1

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

//set the index counter
var i = 0;

//convert all .nav-tabs, except those with the class .keep-tabs
$('.nav-tabs:not(.keep-tabs').each(function(){

    //init variables
    var $select,
        c       = 0,
        $select = $('<select class="mobile-nav-tabs-' +i+ ' mobile-tab-headings "></select>');

    //add unique class to nav-tabs, so each select works independently
    $(this).addClass('nav-tabs-index-'+i);

    //loop though each <li>, building each into an <option>, getting the text from the a href
    $(this).children('li').each(function() {
        $select.append('<option value="'+c+'">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
        c++;
    });

    //insert new <select> above <ul nav-tabs>
    $(this).before($select);

    //increase index counter
    i++
});

//on changing <select> element
$('[class^=mobile-nav-tabs]').on('change', function (e) {

    //get index from selected option
    classArray      = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    tabIndexArray   = classArray[0].split("mobile-nav-tabs-")
    tabIndex        = tabIndexArray[1];

    //using boostrap tabs, show the selected option tab
    $('.nav-tabs-index-'+tabIndex+' li a').eq($(this).val()).tab('show');
});

});
```

Can view the JS fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kingsloi/96ur6epu/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses. I found the one provided by Nathan Hiemstra to be the most simple one and easy to follow and implement.

However I noticed it works in a "one and done" manner. What I mean is once you have selected an option and activated its corresponding panel and have cycled thru all the panels you will notice that the panels stop switching (atleast in bootstrap 4.6.*).

After a bit of digging I found out that the .tab('show') method adds an "active" class to the option element of the select. Makes sense because I am guess this is to be used with nav tabs which are active 1 at a time.

Anyway my simple fix (don't know if it has any side-effects) but seems to work is after the call to .tab('show') on the option element call .removeClass('active'). I figured the selected option is the "active" option anyway so why have this class. But this has made the difference between one and done and working forever.

Hope this little modification helps

Kind Regards...