# Toggleable tabs with button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Make Twitter Bootstrap navbar work like tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767214/make-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-work-like-tabs)

Comment: sorry! but you can't get help with that..please elaborate your question or at-least ask one.

Comment: instenad TABSS put navbar

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: instead of tabs to be a navbar

Comment: when I click a button in the navbar to change my text at the function. excuse the bad English

Comment: We can excuse the bad english, we can't excuse the fact you have put **NO** effort into explaining what you want or what you have tried so far.

Comment: kjlek understood what I wanted and helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do it like this, where they hide the tab ul, and link the buttons to trigger the tabs....

Except in this example, its a select instead of buttons....

[How to toggle Twitter Bootstrap tab panes with <select> <option>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095080/how-to-toggle-twitter-bootstrap-tab-panes-with-select-option)

**EDIT**

More info....

[Make Twitter Bootstrap navbar work like tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767214/make-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-work-like-tabs)

Comment: I need to be instead of TABS navbar

Comment: I get that, but that answer will help guide you, unless you just expect full code handed to you....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767214/make-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-work-like-tabs

Comment: That's it. but the code is not completed by the end of

Comment: Yeah, because this site promotes figuring stuff out for yourself......with what he provides there....its quite simple.  Short of just writing your code for you.....what do you want?

Comment: Thank you. I know now as a going. you are the king