# bootstrap dropdown - open tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, dropdown

i want to choose a option from a dropdown in bootstrap and make a tab active.
does anybody know if it works without use jquery?

if it doesn't work i think i have to catch the onchange event and take the choosen value?!

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle Twitter Bootstrap tab panes with <select> <option>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095080/how-to-toggle-twitter-bootstrap-tab-panes-with-select-option)

Comment: no, because i want to know if i could solve it WITHOUT jquery, and the other solution was WITH jquery.

Comment: But you can't achieve your goal without JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: right yes, but first it wasn't clear for me if i could do it without jquery. and in the other posting it was only explained with jquery. no problem the answer was that i cant do it without jquery and thats okay for me. i solve it with jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab.("show") funtion work with a  tag. He use the href of the  tag to display the right tabs.

I think that there are two different solutions:

1. You can add css string "Display: none" to ul. In this way the JS code is the same and you don't see the nav-tab.

   2. You can change the js code to display directly the tab.

```js
$('#Select').on('change', function (e) {
    $('.tab-pane').hide();
    $('.tab-pane').eq($(this).val()).show(); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <select id='Select'>
        <option value='0'>Tab1</option>
        <option value='1'>Tab2</option>
        <option value='2'>Tab3</option>
        <option value='3'>Tab4</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1">Home content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab2">Profile content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab3">Messages content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab4">Settings content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use jQuery to do this.

```js
$('#Select').on('change', function (e) {
    $('#Tab li a').eq($(this).val()).tab('show'); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <select id='Select'>
        <option value='0'>Tab1</option>
        <option value='1'>Tab2</option>
        <option value='2'>Tab3</option>
        <option value='3'>Tab4</option>
    </select>
</form>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Tab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab4">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1">Home content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab2">Profile content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab3">Messages content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab4">Settings content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx @Simone Bitti, is it possible do activate the tab directly with $('#Tab1').tab('show')?
I tried it but it doesn't work. i havent the <ul>...</ul> i only have the <div class="tab-content"> code in my script!?